# CBOW (Continuous Bag of Word) Understandable Code

Tags: word2vec

Recently I have read word2vec. I wanted to understand **CBOW** (Continuous Bag of Word Model) completely. For this purpose I read a lecture notes and got some understandings and then decided to remove some confusions from code if a good implementation is available. I found a Google code for [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/source/default/source). It have .sh files which means that it would run on linux and .c files are also given but there is a **very less commenting in code**. Also I **did not found any documentation** till now to understand the code in well way.

Then I went through [another implementation](http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html) which is in java but it have its own issues like a famous one, DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file (file name) in url jar:file:

Is there any other implementation available by seeing which one can get better understanding of CBOW preferably in windows instead of linux? If anyone can help me I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER:** This is a link to my own code on GitHub.

I have recently written a C# GPU implementation of CBOW Word2Vec and published on GitHub here: https://github.com/robosoup/Athena

It implements all the features as outlined in Tomas Mikolov's 2013 paper - including sub-sampling frequent terms, dynamic window size and negative sampling.

If you're familiar with C#, this should be pretty easy to understand.